# How to remove \u000a from a string in C#

Tags: c#

I have a String config which is something like

```
<config schemaVersion="2.0" version="63634948757">
\u000a<settings>\u000a        <currentValue>\u000a
```

I want to remove the line return character \u000a. I tried

```
config = config.Replace("\u000a", "");
```

But it doesn't work. Would appreciate it if someone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to escape `\`, use double `\\`

`config = config.Replace("\\u000a", "");`

OR

`config = config.Replace(@"\u000a", "");`